# How to trigger functions in Backbone view concept

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I started to learn `Backbone.js Views`,For my practice purpose I tried the following code.

```
<body>
<div id="search_container"></div>
<input type="text" id="field"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        //var template = _.template( $("#search_template").html(), {data:'ggg'} );
        console.log(this.$el.attributes);
        $('#search_container').html(this.$el);
    },
    events: {
        "click #field": "doSearch"
    },
    doSearch: function( event ){
        console.log('ssss');
        alert('working!!');
    }
});
var search_view = new SearchView({el:"#field"});
</script>
</body>
```

If you observer my code, I added text field into `div`.it's working fine.If you click on `textField` it's not calling `doSearch()` function.

How can I fix This.

Comment: are you sure that the input's id is `field` and that it's inside the `this.$el`? maybe you could show us the generated html :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is the shortened form of [delegateEvents](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents). This method uses [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) under the hood and your selector will filter the *descendants* of the current views' `el`, see Backbone's [`delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-127):

```
this.$el.on(eventName, selector, method);
```

See this fiddle:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V6UPC/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is #field is not inside view, but the view $el itself. To have it working change your event hash to

```
events: {
    "click": "doSearch"
}
```